# (Answered) JSON reading function returning Undefined instead of expected value - Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I am working on a function to read a JSON file based on what is past to it and return the value. Inside the actual function, I can output to the console exactly what I expect, but when I return it *then* output to the console I get undefined instead.

The JSON file I'm working with looks like this:

```
{
    "ECMadrid": "tbd",
    "ECParis": "tbd2"
}
```

The function I use to read the file looks like this:

```
    getReferenceNumber(productName){
        fs.readFile('./filepath.json', 'utf-8', (err, jsonString) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                try {
                    const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
                    console.log("The reference number before returning is: ", data[productName]);
                    return data[productName];
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Error parsing JSON:", err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And I call the function inside a test file like this:

```
let referenceNumber = await jsonHelper.getReferenceNumber("ECMadrid");
await console.log("I got sent: ", referenceNumber);
```

I would expect both of those console logs to output the same result but instead my output is like this (and notably, it outputs the console log that comes after the function call first, which I thought was strange and worth pointing out):

> I got sent: undefined
> The reference number before returning is: tbd

I'm trying to figure out why the getReferenceNumber function is correctly assigning what I want to data[productName] but returning undefined to the class where I'm actually calling it. Thanks in advance for any feedback

Edit: Answered correctly and quickly, thank you!

Comment: `await` does not have any effect on `console.log()`. `console.log()` is synchronous, `await` is used to await the completion of an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getReferenceNumber` is not `async`, and does not return a promise. The only `return` statement is in a nested function, which returns from that function, and *not* from `getReferenceNumber`. Which means `getReferenceNumber` returns no value, which is why you get `undefined.

You probably want [`fsPromises.readFile` instead.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options)

I believe this is equivalent.

```
async getReferenceNumber(productName: string) {
  try {
    const jsonString = await fs.promises.readFile('./filepath.json', 'utf-8')

    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
      console.log("The reference number before returning is: ", data[productName]);
      return data[productName];
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log("Error parsing JSON:", err);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap `readFile` for `readFileSync` to use a synchronous call (if you are okay with it being blocking code).
You can then remove your `await`'s in your test file.